# Moving andorid secure folder between sd cards

Tags: backup, external-sd

I needed to upgrade my sd card size for my phone and have ~4-5k files in my android secure folder. I backed everything up to my laptop and then pushed it onto my new sd card. The copying got interrupted when my laptop went into sleep mode (forgot to disable sleep mode when plugged in without any trackpad movement). I am misisng 80% of the files and i do not know how to merge the good backup onto my phones new sd card

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Android itself doesn't have a built-in secure folder, meaning that this looks like a feature of an app/OS customization instead (e.g. Google Files' Safe Folder, Samsung's Secure Folder, etc.). Could you [edit] and mention the device model and/or the app you are using?

Comment: I am confused, just copy them back from the laptop.